# Access scope with "this" when using $.fn. and $('#test').demo();

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I hope this isn't a very stupid question, but I'm a bit confused regarding how jQuery deals with the `this` property when using its prototype function.

When passing an argument to a function such as `$.fn.demo`, the value of `this` will contain the DOM object passed in the argument, in this case the object matching the selector `#test`:

```
$('#test').demo({test: 'test1'});
```

Is it possible to access the function scope when using jQuery prototype function with an argument?
My aim is to define scope variables dynamically, something that I would normally do using `this['demo'] = 'aaa'`

Where do they get stored if not in `this`?

[Code online](https://jsfiddle.net/5pt0pfxd/5/)

```
$.fn.demo = function(options){
    var helloText = "hello";

    // keeping central set of classnames and selectors
    var classes = {
        wrapper: 'wrapper',
        pepe: 'demo'
    };

    //this has the #test DOM object value, not the function scope
    console.log(this);

    //trying to assign the object keys to the global scope
    for (var key in classes) {
        this[key] = classes[key];
    }

    console.log(helloText);

    //fails to print the value of "pepe", it doens't exist in the scope
    console.log(pepe);
};

$('#test').demo({test: 'test1'});
```

Comment: `this` wouldn't be the DOM object, but the jquery object instance.

Comment: @MinusFour nvm I'm wrong

Comment: If you do `this.pepe` instead of `pepe` it should work

Comment: @MinusFour I want to avoid using object properties. They end up making the code longer and they do not get minified with common minifiers.

Comment: You'd also have to avoid `this[key]` then. The only way you could create variables dynamically would be through eval and that's even worse.

Comment: `$.fn.demo.data = {}` then assign to it like you were assigning to `this`. No name collision possibilities, no hidden vars hanging around, etc. That's assuming you want the data to be shared across all instances. Otherwise, you could use [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data).

Comment: Are you asking what `this` will be for a jQuery plugin or how to store data in one? The question seems to be asking both and is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that your aim, if it is that just adding variable in "this" scope then when you use it you should use "this" like already said by @MinusFour or You want to add variable in function scope then use eval, You can see differences below js Code;

```
$.fn.demo = function(options){
    var helloText = "hello";

    // keeping central set of classnames and selectors
    var classes = {
        wrapper: 'wrapper',
        pepe: 'demo'
    };

    //this has the #test DOM object value, not the function scope
    console.log(this);

    //trying to assign the object keys to the global scope
    for (var key in classes) {
        this[key] = classes[key];
        eval("var " + key+"='"+classes[key]+"'");
    }
    console.log(this);

    console.log(helloText);

    //fails to print the value of "pepe", it doens't exist in the scope
    console.log(this.pepe);
    console.log(pepe);
};

$('#test').demo({test: 'test1'});
```

Answer (score 1):

The global object for browser Javascript is the `window` object. So you can modify part of your code like this and it will work:

```
for (var key in classes) {
    window[key] = classes[key];
}
```

However, writing things into window object is generally a bad idea, as everything can write and read from there. A way to prevent this is:

```js
(function() {
  var myEncapsulatedValues = {};

  var myJQueryFunction = function() {
    var classes = {
      wrapper: 'Yay it works!!',
      pepe: 'demo'
    };
    
    for (var prop in classes) {
      myEncapsulatedValues[prop] = classes[prop];
    }
  };

  myJQueryFunction();

  console.log(myEncapsulatedValues['wrapper']);

})();

// But I cant access encapsulated values here
console.log(typeof myEncapsulatedValues);
```

This is a basic way to simulate encapsulation in Javascript, and it is called IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

There are many things to learn if you are new to Javascript. Scope, Context, Closure, Hoisting, Modules. Even knowing their names would make you more competent in tackling the difficulties you are going to face. You can get the basic idea [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).